# How to define char array in Swift language

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Here is my C code in an Objective-C method

> char addressBuffer[100];

But how to define this char in Swift language?

I try something like this but this doesn't work:

> var addressBuffer : CChar(100)

Here is the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: use `String` instead. If you need a `char[100]`, you should use the C language instead. I don't see a reason for Swift-Code to use a `char[100]` type

Comment: Recall: "Objective-C with out the C"

Comment: I use netServiceDidResolveAddress delegate and in this method I use sockets which are implemented in C language. socket->C language

Comment: so you write the necessary code in Objective-C and use that from Swift...

Comment: By the same token one would tend to think that `char c[100]` is never needed in Objective-C...but it is. There are interoperability issue where a char array is needed. Perhaps if we re-phrase: `Int8[100]`?

Comment: @Michael Wait, Objective-C cannot go away? If we use Swift we will also need to use Objective-C? But I am hearing that Objective-C will go away in a few years, I'm confused. ;-)

Comment: @Zaph I hope Objective-C will not go away. I like it much more than Swift. Maybe I should become a Cobol programmer instead, or write Android apps... No, seriously, I don't like Swift... I like private methods, a non-managed language and I like to know how exactly my code is translated to assembler. It would be much nicer if ObjC were just extended with value types and generics. No need to create a new language.

Comment: @Michael I see I am loosing much with Swift and that there are to many optional shortcuts that are definitely affect readability. Every devs are going to come up with a bewildering variety of coding styles, a "Code of Babble". I am already seeing operator over-loadings that just shouldn't happen, the worst of C++ has arrived.

Comment: @Michael No. I have a method which contains C type variables and... And now I would like to implement the obj-c code in Swift. But i dont want to change the C codes. I just want to make changes with the C code to apply the swift compiler

Comment: Please see the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: Another reason for using C chars in Swift is `SecRandomCopyBytes` and avoiding to use `NSMutableData`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

that is the way to get a nice unicode character array in *Swfit*:

```
var charArray: Array<Character> = Array(count: 100, repeatedValue: "?")
```

if fills your array with 100 question marks, initially.

## update

with `CChar`, for instance:

```
var charArray: Array<CChar> = Array(count: 100, repeatedValue: 32) // 32 is the ascii space
```

Comment: Okey maybe it will be good but how to define a char array (100) with CChar type?

Comment: what's the difference between them?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp, the `CChar` is literally an alias for `Int8` in _Swift_.

Answer (score 7):

This Swift code seems to allocate something usable as a C char array of size 100 (for C interoperation needs):

```
var addressBuffer = [Int8](count: 100, repeatedValue: 0)

// test it
addressBuffer[0] = 65 // 'A'
addressBuffer.withUnsafePointerToElements() { (addrBuffPtr : UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> () in
      // use pointer to memory
      var x0 = addrBuffPtr.memory
      println("The ASCII value at index 0 is \(x0)")

      var myCOpaquePointer = COpaquePointer(addrBuffPtr)
      // use C pointer for interoperation calls
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html pls see it

Comment: Did you find some problem with the documentation?

Comment: C signed char variables (if you need them for interoperation with some existing C library using type char) aren't for use with unicode data.

Answer (score 6):

hotpaw2's answer in **Swift 4+**

```swift
var addressBuffer = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 100)
```